setVolumen in Agora for IOs
I'm trying to "mute" certain users by volume, and leaving others with a default volume. On Android, MacOs and Windows devices, this works fine, however, on iOS this is not the case and when a user should be "muted" they are still being heard.
...
 if (this.mainHostMute) {
   user.audioTrack.setVolume(AgoraAudioConfig.CREATOR_VOLUME);
 } else {
   user.audioTrack.setVolume(AgoraAudioConfig.DEFAULT_VOLUME);
 }
 user.audioTrack.play();
...

Where CREATOR_VOLUME: 0 and DEFAULT_VOLUME: 100
I am using the following versions.
"agora-rtc-sdk-ng": "^4.18.0",
"agora-rtm-sdk": "^1.5.1",

I've tried to find references to this problem, maybe some limitations with iOS in the setVolume for audioTrack? Could it be something related to the versions I'm using?
Muting a user by volume is for control with certain roles, this works fine for other devices, but on IOs is where the problem occurs and it doesn't seem to apply volume changes.
